# Why does saving only work for creating and not updating?

Tags: php, laravel, crud

Whenever I run a code like this

```
$foo = Foo::find(1);
echo $foo->bar; // echoes 400
$foo->bar = 300;
echo $foo->bar; // echoes 300 
$foo->save(); 
echo $foo->bar; // echoes 300
$foo = Foo::find(1);
echo $foo->bar; // echoes 400 - it didn't save! no changes to the table
```

Nothing happens. But this works:

```
$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar = 200;
echo $foo->bar; // echoes 200;
$foo->save();   // a new entry is added to my table
```

I can't update (changes are made to the model but it doesn't save), but adding new entries works. Why?

(Foo extends Model class, bar is a column)

Comment: Are you sure that your object have an ID key? Otherwise Laravel don't know which row update.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? What database are you using? Can you also post the content of your model?

Comment: The only scenario I can think of where `save()` wont *save* is if you are protecting the `bar` from mass assignement !

Comment: Does your model have `protected $fillable = ['bar'];`?

Answer (score 0):

I had 'Id' as header for ID's. Changing it to 'id' made everything work.

Answer (score 0):

every models has 2 property $original and $attributes . [Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L22)
if you use Find ,model sync result to orginal .[Method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L916)

and you set new data, only update $attributes['bar'], $original['bar'] same on database value.

if you use save() method ,update database and $original again sync $attributes.
after update() method model dont need create new select query just update $original